# Integer Error in Python Flask

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I have Implemented a program that takes in input from the url as:

```
lat = float(request.args.get('lat'))
lon = float(request.args.get('long'))
```

Then through Haversine formula compares this lat/lon to another set of lat and lon provided through an html form and captures in an ajax object as:

```
objt = {'lat': request.args.get('lat'), 'lon': request.args.get('long')}
sdata.append(objt);
sdatav = json.dumps(sdata):
```

It returns the input fine, however when I try to compare it, I get an error saying:

> string indices must be integers, not str

On this line:

```
distances = (distance(int((v['lat'],v['lon'],lat,lon))) for v in sdatav)
```

and

```
for lat_lng, d in sorted(zip(sdatav, distances)):
```

The whole code is Below:

```
@app.route('/')
def home(): 
  objt = {'lat': request.args.get('lat'), 'lon': request.args.get('long')}
  sdata.append(objt);
  sdatav = json.dumps(sdata)
  listlat = []

  def distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    p = 0.017453292519943295#degree to radian
    a = 0.5 - cos((lat2-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p)*cos(lat2*p) * (1-  cos((lon2-lon1)*p)) / 2
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a))#print in km

  lat = float(request.args.get('lat'))
  lon = float(request.args.get('long'))

  #Compare the given lat/lon against the set and return values
  distances = (distance(v['lat'],v['lon'],lat,lon) for v in sdatav)
  for lat_lng, d in sorted(zip(sdatav, distances),key = itemgetter(1)):
    lpo = (lat_lng['lat'], lat_lng['lon'],str(d) + "kms"  ) 
    listlat.append(lpo)
  return listlat
  #return json.dumps(sdata)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port = 5001,debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

```
sdatav = json.dumps(sdata):
```

`sdatav` is a string.  You probably want to use `sdata` like this:

```
distances = (distance(float(v['lat']), float(v['lon']), lat, lon) for v in sdata)
```

Comment: That generates another error as :unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'unicode' in a = 0.5 - cos((lat2-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p)*cos(lat2*p) * (1-cos((lon2-lon1)*p)) / 2

Comment: Need to cast to float?